# Why MediaPlayer throws NOT present error when creating instance of it?

Tags: android, adt, android-mediaplayer, logcat

When creating an instance of MediaPlayer LogCat shows this error:

> QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present

Why is that and is it normal?

Sample:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class MainActivity extends Activity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means your platform does not support QCMediaPlayer. QCMediaPlayer provides extended APIs and interfaces to get and set MPD attributes for DASH protocol in compatible Snapdragon builds. So, this error should not affect on media playing in normal case

Check this sources to find out more details:

[QCMediaPlayer.java](https://github.com/fallowu/slim_hardware_qcom_media/blob/master/QCMediaPlayer/com/qualcomm/qcmedia/QCMediaPlayer.java)

Comment: If the platform doesn't support QCMediaPlayer, why would it try to launch QCMediaPlayer?

Comment: And why does the Android operating system allow this and that app, as well as itself, to throw out error messages in the first place? Shouldn't that be removed completely in a commercially launched system that should be out of debug mode?

Comment: This should not be accepted; it gives no information on how to solve this problem, which is that on some platforms MediaPlayer is totally non-functional.

Comment: Is there any solution to prevent QCMediaPlayer from being invoked in the first place?

Comment: What your mean "your platform" ?

Comment: What is the 'normal case'? Can these errors be safely ignored?

Answer (score 8):

I know that this is not an answer for "Why" this is happening but if someone wants to make it work (at least for me it worked), you can initialize the `MediaPlayer` not by creating a new instance and setting the data source but by creating it using the `static` method `create`:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(sound_file_path));
```

or

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundRedId, loop);
```

Comment: I received the error with this way in the first place. In my case I know the targeted mp3 file doesn't exist, maybe it is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

adding `mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` solved problem for me. Initially I tried with other types however it didn't work.

Comment: This was the solution!

Comment: Not work for me! Api 19(KitKat), lg l65 .Create MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer() case.

Answer (score 1):

Bizarrely, what seemed to fix this for me is restarting Android Studio. Then I ran in debug mode and it started working, and haven't seen the error since. Weird!

Answer (score 1):

I have added this code:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.menumusic);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

And it was not working, what seemed to fix this for me is **restarting Android Studio**.
Hope this will help someone.