# What is QCMediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an Android application trying to play a video with VideoViewer:

```
    mainActivityView.videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mainActivityView.videoView.setVideoPath("/Movies/" + "video1.mp4");
    mainActivityView.videoView.requestFocus();
    mainActivityView.videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mainActivityView.videoView.start();
        }
    });
    mainActivityView.videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mainActivityView.videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            mainActivityView.videoView.setVideoPath("");
        }
    });
```

but I keep getting a crash with a run time error:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

However before the error I am seeing this in red:

```
03-25 23:00:55.833    5106-5106/com.passa.videobooth E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
03-25 23:00:55.853    5106-5118/com.passa.videobooth E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
```

I have tried searching the internet trying to figure out what this is or means with no luck. Please Help!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it