# Workaround for Android QCMediaPlayer not present

Tags: android

My LogCat gives me this error

```
E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
```

So I searched for it and I found out that it looks like the device doesn't support the QCMediaPlayer. What else can I do to play Audio Files and how can I check if the QCMediaPlayer is supported?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why MediaPlayer throws NOT present error when creating instance of it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it     The errors don't seem to be relevant according to the answers there

Answer (score 0):

Mine Got solved by using static create method of MediaPlayer:

```
MediaPlayer player= MediaPlayer.create(cntx, Uri.parse(this.path));
```

for resource files:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(cntx, sound_resource_id, loop);
```

Answer (score -3):

1:Check whether the AndroidManifest.xml is to add the

```
<"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

2:Some people say that after the android version 4.0 online, do not use the new ，change .creat

Have a try, the hope can help you