# Android - QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer not present

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to play a short sound when clicking a button, but logcat says "QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present"

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it) but it didnt really help me, so i decided to ask again.

```
mp.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.sound);
mp.start();
```

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it

Comment: @HendraAnggrian sorry, but did you actually read my post? i already said, that this does not help me.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: @pratiti-systematix i am using soundpool instead of media player

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using the SoundPool class instead of the MediaPlayer class.