# Android - QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present - unable to play sound at all

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play audio from Url, using the below code:

```
            String url = "1451739079.mp3";
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                player.setDataSource(url);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
```

But this is not at all working, showing error in logcat as:

```
   E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
```

I've already visited [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it),
but of no help.

Please suggest how to play audio from Url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why MediaPlayer throws NOT present error when creating instance of it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it)? Since the answer is given there.

Comment: Yeah, I already mentioned visiting that link....but of no help

Comment: > It means your platform does not support QCMediaPlayer.

Although, I'm not completely sure that your url is correct in any way. Try playing a correct http url.

Comment: okay, but then, how can I play media from Url?

Comment: So your question is not what the error means as I first understood, rather how you should do this? Try to rephrase your question. And try replacing 1451739079.mp3 by https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3, since that first url that you have is pointing to nowhere.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I asked for, check the last line of my post. The url link is just for sample, I'm using a well-formed url, which is working fine on browser.