# JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present

Tags: android, media-player, avaudioplayer

While playing audio ,I am getting JNI Media player not present error.Below I have posted logcat error.

**Logcat:**

```
 E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
 E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 2
 E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
 E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

Anyone can help me with this.

Comment: were you able to solve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why MediaPlayer throws NOT present error when creating instance of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it)