# How to solve QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present Error?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to play `.mp3` file from `ListView` I have tried following but its not working

```
public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    View myView;
   private  String[] theNamesOfFiles;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mp=new MediaPlayer();
        myView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout,container,false);

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Ringtones");
            File[] filelist = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                    return !pathname.isHidden();
                }
            });
            theNamesOfFiles = new String[filelist.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < theNamesOfFiles.length; i++) {
                theNamesOfFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();
                int pos = theNamesOfFiles[i].lastIndexOf(".");
                if (pos > 0) {
                    theNamesOfFiles[i] = theNamesOfFiles[i].substring(0, pos);
                }
            }

        ListView listview=(ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.RecordingList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> listviewAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theNamesOfFiles
        );
        listview.setAdapter(listviewAdapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);
            }
        });
        return myView;
    }
    public void playSong(int songIndex)
    {
        //Play Songs
        mp.reset();
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),theNamesOfFiles[songIndex]);
        mp.start();
    }
}
}
```

can anyone tell me how to do this  and what i'm missing ?

**EDIT** 
I have tried with `Uri` passing as

```
 Uri myUri = Uri.parse(theNamesOfFiles[position]);
```

but the file is not playing and the Error Log is as follows

> QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present

can anyone tell me whats going wrong and what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in playSong method

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/mp3/example.mp3");
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: the path of the filename?

Comment: On your file list I suppose  maybe  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Ringtones" + "/"+ theNamesOfFiles[songIndex];

Comment: the problem is how to pass the path of the clicked item into Uri?

Comment: try passing a route that you know

Comment: i have given the path but the  file is not playing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the log

> QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present

is not related.

[Why MediaPlayer throws NOT present error when creating instance of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it)

I would add a `progressListener` to see if it's playing but it's not outputting for some reason.

Comment: what is the reason behind that and the link you have  given also don't have any answer

Comment: There are a number of reasons why the media player wouldn't play music. I'm wondering if it actually is playing (or thinks it is), but it's just not outputting. I would also add a log statement for your file along the lines of `file.exists()` to make sure that you don't have a path error.