# Playing .M3U links using Media Player

Tags: java, android, m3u

I need to play .M3U urls using Media Player, but it is not working:
Here is my code:

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://xxxxxxxxx/1.m3u");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

I have read all related question in this regards on stackoverflow but it is not help me,

Also I have tried to extract the .M3U by using this method:

```
    public ArrayList<String> readURLs(String url) {
    if (url == null) return null;
    ArrayList<String> allURls = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        URL urls = new URL(url);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urls
                .openStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            allURls.add(str);

        }
        Toast.makeText(this, allURls + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("URL", String.valueOf(allURls));
        in.close();
        return allURls;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

But it was not working also when I call it

```
readURLs ("http://xxxxxxx.m3u");
```

So please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Comment: @TiagoOrnelas Thank you for your care, kindly find the logcat error below:


`E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
07-25 12:18:26.474 11277-11833/com.app.app E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
07-25 12:18:26.513 11277-11833/com.app.app E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set`

Comment: Please refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087804/should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-mediaplayer-error-android

Comment: Did you test .m3u link before for example:
`http://109.94.2.96:8888/1.m3u`since the above post not solve my problem

Answer (score -1):

I would try to initialize the `MediaPlayer` differently:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("http://xxxxxxxxx/1.m3u"));
```

Reference:

[Why MediaPlayer throws NOT present error when creating instance of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it)

Also don't forget to release the `MediaPlayer` once you are done with it.

```
player.release();
```

**EDIT:**

I explored the `.m3u`, but these contains other `.m3u8`playlists. I would recommend you to use **Google's ExoPlayer** instead which plays almost everything. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just tried it but it throws the following error,
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()'`

Could you please test the code with actual M3U url like: `http://109.94.2.96:8888/1.m3u`

Comment: unfortunately Google's ExoPlayer  is not support .m3u as they mentioned in Github

Comment: Exoplayer supports HLS (m3u8), in your m3u I see mostly m3u8 ones :)

Comment: Thank you for your continues support, Can I play ExoPlayer as sound stream only?

Comment: I believe ExoPlayer supports video as well