# How can i check if there is a speaker that i can use on device?

Tags: android, media-player

Actually i'm developing an app for Zebra MC3300 that previously was developed for another device where all was working as well but on MC3300 the app crash every time i'm trying to use MediaPlayer with the following error:

> QCMediaPlayer could not be located....

So i'm starting to think that this device doesn't have any speacker but actually on it [specsheet](https://www.jdata.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/MC3300_EN.pdf) it says that the device has it.

So the question it how can i test for any available speacker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That device does have a speaker - you can see from the integration guide at https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/mobile-computers/mc33-android-v8.1-ug-en.pdf (table 3).  Looks like the device does not support QCMediaPlayer - this answer is related: [Why MediaPlayer throws NOT present error when creating instance of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501086/why-mediaplayer-throws-not-present-error-when-creating-instance-of-it)

Comment: What should i use instead of QCMediaPlayer to play raw sound on that device so?

Comment: The point is that even if i run a default sound in Android Settings android just crash...

Comment: I do not have a device to test but if you look at that related SO post I linked above there are a few answers posted by users who managed to work around a similar error.